# Laravel Relations To a Pivot Table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

In my Laravel app I have 3 Models ("Material", "Element" & "Reference") and their relation is like this:

- "Material" is many to many to "Element"
- "Each Material Element Relationship" is polymorphic many to many to "Reference"

Considering that I want to get all the info about these models in a single eager loading, what is the best practice to create the Models? Should I use a custom pivot model?

> Update for better explanation:

I get the following result by using this code

> Material::with('elements')->first();

What I'm looking for is the references for each pivot of ElementMaterial.

```
{
    id: 1001,
    name: "Butter",
    elements: [
    {
        id: 203,
        unit: "g",
        name: "Protein",
        pivot: {
            material_id: 1001,
            element_id: 203,
            element_amount: 0.85
            /*I NEED REFERENCES HERE!*/
        },
    },
    {
        id: 204,
        unit: "g",
        name: "FAT",
        pivot: {
            material_id: 1001,
            element_id: 204,
            element_amount: 81.11
            /*I NEED REFERENCES HERE!*/
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean by single eager loading, what do you try to achieve?

Comment: @deczo thanks for caring, I updated my question for a better explanation.

Comment: Still don't know what you need there. What are those references? I can see you already use `withPivot`, so I wonder what else should be there. Do you have another relation to the pivot itself?

Comment: Well, References here are a model. It has a polymorphic many to many relation with some other models. Comparing to Laravel doc, it's like a tag.

Comment: Check my answer and just a note: it will be easier to read your setup, thus help, when you paste the relations instead of describing them like you did

Answer (score 4):

You definitely need custom pivot model for this. I assume you know how to create one, so here's just a suggestion on how to work with it:

```
// ElementMaterial = pivot model, elementMaterials = relation name
// OtherModel = model related to the above, otherModels = 1-m relation name

$material = Material::with('elements')->first();

// now to access otherModels you need something like this:
$material->elements->first()->pivot->otherModels;
```

Which will execute db query for each pivot model, overkill.

There is currently no way to eager load anything on the pivot model, even setting `$with` on the pivot itself won't help here.

---

You could instead do this:

```
$material = Material::with('elements', 'elementMaterials.otherModels')->first();

// but now you can access elements directly:
$material->elements; //collection of Element models

// and other models through the pivot model:
$material->elementMaterials; // collection of pivot models
$material->elementMaterials->first()->otherModels; // collection of OtherModels
```

But there is no link between `$material->elements` and `$material->...->otherModels`.

---

That's why I suggest you **access both relations through the pivot** model:

```
$material = Material::with('elementMaterials.elements', 'elementMaterials.otherModels')->first();

// then
$material->elementMaterials->first()->elements;
$material->elementMaterials->first()->otherModels;
```